Bayesian model comparison for mixed models
If one wants to obtain the bayes factors per parameter which method should we use?
a) define models with increasing complexity
m0 <- brm(Sepal.Length ~ (1 | Species), data = iris)
m1 <- brm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + (1 | Species), data = iris)
m2 <- brm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + (Petal.Length | Species), data = iris)
m3 <- brm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width + (Petal.Length | Species), data = iris)
m4 <- brm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length * Petal.Width + (Petal.Length | Species), data = iris)

b) exclude the parameter of interest
m0 <- brm(Sepal.Length ~ 0 + Petal.Length * Petal.Width + (Petal.Length | Species), data = iris)
m1 <- brm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Length :Petal.Width + (Petal.Length | Species), data = iris)
m2 <- brm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Petal.Length :Petal.Width + (Petal.Length | Species), data = iris)
m3 <- brm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width + (Petal.Length | Species), data = iris)
m4 <- brm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length * Petal.Width + (Petal.Length | Species), data = iris)

If the first method is the correct one, how can one do it with multiple main effects and interactions?
e.g., what if one has 4 main effects and its corresponding interactions?
model <- brm(Sepal.Length ~ z*x*c*v + (1 | Species), data = iris)

What models would we need to fit in order of increased complexity? I think it is easy to anticipate one per main effect, but then would we need to do each main effect separately with each separate interaction term and only then bring everything together?
I can't use Savage-Dickey density ratio instead because we are using uninformed priors as we decided to run these after the frequentist models so we did not want to bias the results to be in line with the frequentist results.
